# Using Graphics object outside of the paint() method for a fractal java

Tags: java, graphics, paint

I am trying to draw a fractal tree, and currently my design gleamed from other people's work is using graphics objects outside of the paint() method for recursion. Will this result in anything at all?

Comment: What is your definition of "outside"?

Comment: @SargeBorsch outside as I am passing it as a parameter to the tree drawing method.

Comment: @ZhehaoChen if lifespan of your reference to it doesn't extend over return from paint() method, then it is not really "outside" and this is not a special kind.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a Graphics object (or even the backing array) from a BufferedImage and draw on that, then in paintComponent() you can just draw the image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `Graphics` context as a parameter to your `drawMethod(Graphics g)`, then invoke than method *withing* the `paint` method.  `drawMethod(g);`, `g` being the `Graphics` context of the `paint` method

```
public class SomeClass {
    public void drawMethod(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello World", 50, 50);
    }
}

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        someClass.drawMethod(g);
    }
}
```